# Page events are not triggered while navigating between pages in multipage html web files

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am trying to understand jquery mobile page events in multi page html web page.

when I am trying to  navigate to window2 within the index1.html , the page events are being triggered and transition is happening.

However if I try to navigate between index1.html to index3.html the page events of index3.html are not being triggered and page transition is happening.

when I tried with adding data-ajax ="false" to index3.html href, the page events of page3.html are being fired. However , the transition is not happening.

can someone pls help me understand 
1)why the events are not getting fired? 
2)issues in  using data-ajax="false"

Below are the pages I am trying to navigate between

**index1.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="home">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  <div data-role="content">
    <p> Window content 1 </p>  
    <a href="#win2"> Window 2 (into the DOM) </a>
    <br /><br />

    <a href="index3.html" data-transition="pop" > 
          Window 3 in index3.html (data-dom-cache=false) </a>
    <br /><br />


    <br /><br />
  </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="win2" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Window 2</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p> Window content 2 </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

    $(document).bind ("pagebeforeload", function (event, data)
{
  alert ("pagebeforeload data.url = " + data.url);
});

$(document).bind ("pageload", function (event, data)
{
  alert ("pageload data.url = ");
});

$(document).bind ("pageloadfailed", function (event, data)
{
  alert ("pageloadfailed data.url = " + data.url);
});


$("#home").on ("pagebeforecreate", function (event)
{
  alert ("pagebeforecreate id=" + this.id);
});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").on ("pagecreate", function (event)
{
  alert ("pagecreate id=" + this.id);
});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").on ("pageinit", function (event)
{
  alert ("pageinit id=" + this.id);
});


$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagebeforeshow", function (event, ui)
{
  alert("pagebefore show");

});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pageshow", function (event, ui)
{
    alert("pageshow");

});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagebeforehide", function (event, ui)
{
        alert("pagebeforehide");
});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagehide", function (event, ui)
{
        alert("pagehide");
});



**index3.html**

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=text/html;charset=iso-8859-1 />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head> 

<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="win3" data-add-back-btn="true">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Window 3</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p> Window content 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagebeforeshow", function (event, ui)
{
  alert("pagebefore show3");

});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pageshow", function (event, ui)
{
    alert("pageshow3");

});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagebeforehide", function (event, ui)
{
        alert("pagebeforehide3");
});

$("div:jqmData(role=page)").bind ("pagehide", function (event, ui)
{
        alert("pagehide3");
});



</script>
```

Comment: If we've been of help, perhaps you could accept one of our answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called *Single Page Model*, not *Multi-Page*.

As JQM uses Ajax Navigation to switch between pages, when you call an external page e.g. Index2.html, it loads first `data-role=page` in that page and it neglects all other tags.

Hence, to solve you first problem, you need to place JS code of that page inside `data-role=page` to get loaded within the page.

When you use `data-ajax=false` or `rel=external`, you prevent JQM from loading page via Ajac and instead it is load via HTTP as a fresh page with all tags loaded. That's why il event works.

Comment: events are fired when I wrote the events inside data-role="page". But is this standard way of doing this? Ideally we should write all the script func before the data-role="page". Please guide me on the best practice.

Comment: No. Code goes inside the 'page' Everything outside of data-role=page is ignored after the first page.

Comment: so I assume here after to include the page events and scripts inside data-role="page". Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

So some simple explanation.....

1) The events most likely are firing and you just aren't seeing the output. This is quite common, you should try using different events to ensure you are using the correct one. Post some code via a jsfiddle and we can help you debug it.

2) If you turn ajax off for a link you are effectively turning off the ajax transitions and you just load the page as if it were accessed directly. If when you load the page like this, you do see the expected results, it proves that the page events are firing.

Take a look here for some explanation of the order in which events fire;

http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: as I am trying to navigate between multiple singlepage templates , I may not be able to post the code in the jsfiddel for debugging.Pls guide.

Comment: There's nothing anyone can do then.

Comment: events are fired when I wrote the events inside data-role="page". But is this standard way of doing this? Ideally we should write all the script func before the data-role="page". Is this the ideal way to trigger events? thanks for the support.

Comment: You really need to read a bit more about events and then try different events for the bits that don't seem to be working.

Comment: You've currently got all your script outside the HTML tags. That wouldn't even work on a simple HTML page let alone a jqm one. All script needs to be inside the page div.