# jQuery docment.ready not getting fired from second screen in Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

jQuery docment.ready not getting fired from second screen whereas it is getting fired in first/initial screen.

jQuery Mobile is also included in the html, does jQuery Mobile blocking document.ready, I read somewhere we have to use jQuery Mobile’s “pageinit” instead of “document.ready”. But this application is developed for **all platforms – Desktop, Tablets and Mobile**.

So in this case, what would be the appropriate solution? Changing from document.ready to pageinit across all pages is tedious.

Comment: What is "second screen" ?

Comment: JQM is a framework so to make things work you need to abide by the rules of that framework. dont take shortcuts because you find them tedious

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23302340/1771795

Answer (score 0):

jquery-mobile isn't blocking `$( document ).ready( )`

The ready event is fired when the DOM is fully loaded.
[Jquery API Doc of .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

One of the biggest advantages of jquery-mobile is the ajax navigation. If you click a link, jqm don't load the entire page again. No! It's loading only the div with role="page" and add this to the DOM. **And while the DOM isn't loading again, you will not get a second `ready` event.**

To get control over you app, you have to take advantage of the events from jquery-mobile. You can detect exactly, what page is displayed, you can detect, when a page is loaded (via AJAX) into the DOM.

---

There are a lot of interesting events in jquery-mobile. pageshow and pagecreate (not pageinit, because pageinit is deprecated in 1.4.0 in favor of pagecreate)
I included some basics examples. But there are a lot more events and ways to listen for them.

[jquery-mobile Pagecontainer API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/) 
[jquery-mobile Events API](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/)

### pagecreate

**pagecreate (document, one)**
This will be execute once a page is created. Notice i use one and not on.
If you use on instead of one, this event will be triggered  for every page, when the page is created and enhanced.

```
$( document ).one( "pagecreate", function( event ) { 

});
```

**pagecreate (specific page)**
this will be triggered when the page with the id of page1 is created.

```
$("#page1" ).on( "pagecreate", function( event ) {

});
```

### pageshow

**pageshow (document)**
This will be triggered everytime a page is shown.

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function( event ) {

});
```

**pageshow (specific page)**
This will be triggered every time the page with id of page1 is shown.

```
$("#page1" ).on("pageshow", function( event ) {

});
```

Comment: Yes, I understood dom ready is not getting fired since DOM is not loading again, I mentioned pageinit since the jQuery Mobile version is lower and also can't upgrade now. As I mentioned it is tedious job to change or add pageinit or pagecreate or other events across all pages. Looking for a simpler solution.